# Color Blending in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using Photoshop and I'm trying to create a multi-colored background image similar to the one found at http://www.xtorrent.com (the full URL is http://d2aqrl5xrc2ptj.cloudfront.net/images/Main1.jpg).  Does anyone know a good way of doing this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: There are so many ways to do this, so many techniques that would apply, that I can't see it as a useful question here. Best you google "photoshop blending modes" and "photoshop compositing" and get some tutorials on basic Photoshop technique, then if you have a more focused question, ask that.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson Maybe I'm grabbing too hard on what you said about there being too many techniques and that you dont see it as useful question. The way I see it.. almost anything that you can do with photoshop can be done in multiple different ways, so I fail to see your point.

Comment: Basically, a complete answer would require a couple of chapters from a beginner's guide to Photoshop before getting into the specifics of creating an effect like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can get this effect using radial gradients and difference layers.

The technique is pretty simple, but you'll need to play around with it to get just the colors you want.

1. Start with a simple black-to-white linear gradient fill on the bottom layer.
2. Here you start experimenting, but to replicate what I did, change to a radial gradient and select the blue-red-yellow gradient preset (if you haven't changed your presets, it's the 6th gradient in the first row).  If you HAVE changed them, create a new gradient with blue on one side, yellow on the other, and red right in the middle.
3. On each of three new layers, draw a radial gradient in a random size (not too big), and in random locations.
4. Change each of these layers' blending mode to DIFFERENCE. You should see the effect now.
5. By varying the size, shape, and color of the layers, many, many combinations can be achieved.
6. For the window, a simply created a 10-px rounded rectangle, set an outer glow of blue (to transparent, the default).  Changed the size to 24 and the blend mode of the layer effect to difference.

[image: layers_palette]

[image: radial_gradients_difference]

That's it!  I hope this helps.